# Install a SDK remotely without bundling into the app

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, swift-package-manager, swift-package

We have the Native iOS and Android apps which are already considerably larger in size. Planning to integrate a new SDK into the app which would increase the app size considerably (> 200mb).

To mitigate this, on Android we are using [Android Expansion APK's](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files). Is there a similar approach on iOS to remotely install SDK on app launch or navigation to a page without bundling the SDK into the build? FYI - using Swift Package manager.

Comment: No, all executable code must be included in the bundle you upload to AppStore Connect for signing by Apple. You can use on-demand downloads only for additional content such as media.  I don't believe that you can use expansion apks to add executable code on Android either.